# Bash command line gets compressed for long lines

Tags: command-line, bash

Some shells seem to have a feature where a long command is compressed and partially hidden. For instance the following command:

`$ echo this is a really long command line that goes on and on and on and on`

Might be displayed as:

`$ y long command line that goes on and on and on and on <`

Depending on how long the prompt is and how wide the terminal is.  Anyway, my question is what is this feature called and how do I turn it off?

Comment: Try quotes `"` around your statement after the echo and at the end of the line.  e.g.  `echo "this is a really long command line that goes on and on and on and on"`

Answer (score 0):

Different shells implement this differently and the options are named differently

`bash` has ability to unset horizontal scroll mode in side `.inputrc` like so

```
set horizontal-scroll-mode On
```

`dash` does it by default , but I've found no indication of an option to turn it on/off in the man page

`ksh` has `set -o multiline` option for that, while its derivative `mksh`  does not seem to have any option.

The ability to unset it is always available through use of `\` character. To un-wrap long lines type in `\` and immediately press Enter. Don't add additional space or other chars - hit `\`, hit Enter.